# How to access a ngform name from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to check if the elements on the current html page (being rendered using ui-view) are dirty or pristine before I navigate to next tab.

Parent page:

```
<div class="inner-menu">
    <nav>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs edit-menu" role="tablist">
          <!-- location 1 -->
          <li ng-repeat="innerTab in innerTabListArr" ng-click="switchTab($index, $event)">
            <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="">{{innerTab.text}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view="innerTabHolder" name="currForm"></div>      
  </div>
```

and the HTML template that will be rendered to innerTabHolder view is :

```
<div class="edit-general" id="General">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="generalForm">
        <label for="inputL3" class="control-label">Text</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="gn.myMdl">
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <!-- location 2 -->
                  <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="switchTab(generalForm, $event)"> BCK </button>
                  <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="saveGen()">Save Above</button>
                  <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="switchTab(generalForm, $event)"> FWD </button>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </form>                            
 </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple tabs that will get rendered into the view. And this is the controller I have:

```
myApp.controller('compTabCtrl',[ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'mainWebService',
function($rootScope, $scope, $state, mainWebService){

  $scope.innerTabListArr = [{"text" : "Tab 1"},{"text" : "Tab 2"}];

  $scope.switchInnerTab = function(tabId, event){

  };
}]);
```

---

Ok, so this is basic outline and I believe, I have covered all parts. Now, my issue is I am not able to pass the form : "generalForm" into switchTab function at location 1 where as I can do the same at location 2.

I am using the form's `$dirty` and `$pristine` to check if the user has made any changes to the form. So, while clicking on the tab for navigation, the form becomes undefined.

How do I access the `$dirty` property of sub-view in controller.

Plunker for demo :

https://plnkr.co/edit/06F5JfXltinyxrZbbc14?p=preview

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I correctly understood what you want: You want to access the variables within the sub view from the main controller? Usually in my applications every view has its own controller and I use services to communicate between them.

Comment: I have got only 1 controller for all the sub-view. This demo is a small part of a huge project. So, yes, you pointed it right, I want to access the variables in sub view in my controller. Since, there is only one controller, for all the four views, I think, this should be possible.

Comment: Ok, why not more simpler : `<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="saveGeneral()" ng-disabled="page1.name == null || page1.name == ''">Save</button>`

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to verify this, but in my opinion the `ui-view` has its own scope. I think there is a tool called batarang to check the scope variables. And parent scopes can't access child scopes. If I log $scope I also don't see the form.

Comment: Anyways I would just give each tab its own controller und pack the logic into a service. You probably want to send/do anything with the data in the end. This should not be done in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to access the variable always use $scope

access curForm using

```
$scope.curForm.$dirty
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined at Scope.$scope.switchInnerTab. 
$scope.currForm gives undefined.

Comment: please check the plunker